# Are there any Performance SLA for Google Cloud Datastore?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform

I want to know the performance related data of Google Cloud Datastore like QPS and 
maximum throughput related data. 
Any information regarding these and factors which these details depends on is also preferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is not a performance SLA for Cloud Datastore, only an [availability SLA](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/sla).

It is unlikely that QPS would be an issue for you as I'd be almost certain there are larger QPS, higher throughput projects using it than you are likely to have. A correctly designed system can run millions of QPS against Datastore. (If you're seriously looking at a 1M+ QPS load on Datastore, we should talk)

As a historical reference, the team announced handling [4.5 trillion transactions](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2013/05/reducing-app-engine-datastore-pricing-by-up-to-25-percent.html)  per month back in mid 2013 (that'd be a sustained an avg of 1.7M QPS for every second of the month). You can assume that it has grown significantly since then.